# asp.net mvc SMS Service using twilio

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i using twilio to send sms verification  code when add phone Number to account 
and when i debug my app the usermanager.smsSerivice  is null while i regesterd it in identitiyconfig here is my code

```
        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
```

Comment: Where do you initialise `manager`?

Comment: in at the controller " manageController"    `public ManageController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        } `

Comment: `public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }`

Answer (score 1):

You can call SmsService without a manager like below:

```
 var message = new IdentityMessage
 {
    Destination = phoneNumber,
    Body = "Your verification code is: " + code
 };

 await new SmsService().SendAsync(message);
```